# Spark join always stuck on the same task, how can I debug?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using `pyspark` to run a join of this sort:

```
rdd1=sc.textFile(hdfs_dir1).map(lambda row: (getKey1(row),getData1(row)))
rdd2=sc.textFile(hdfs_dir2).map(lambda row: (getKey2(row),getData2(row)))
result=rdd1.join(rdd2).collect()
```

The job executes the first `300` tasks quite fast (~seconds each), and hangs when reaching task `301/308`, even when I let it run for days.

I tried to run the `pyspark` shell with different configuration (number of workers, memory, cpus, cores, shuffle rates) and the result is always the same.

What can be the cause ? and how can I debug it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collect` will try to fetch the result of your join in the application driver node and you will run into memory issues.

The join operation will cause a lot of shuffle operation, but you can reduce this by using bloom filters ([Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)). You construct a bloom filter for the keys in one partition, broadcast and `filter` the other partition. After applying this operations you should expect smaller RDDs (if you do not have the exact same keys in both of them) and your `join` operation should be much faster.

The bloom filter can be collected efficiently since you can combine the bits set by one element with the bits set by another element with OR, which is associative and commutative.

Comment: The bloom filter suggestion sounds like a great idea, could you please refer me to  a code snippet that implements this concept ?

Comment: `rdd.map(lambda x : bloomHashFct(x)).reduce(lambda hash1,hash2: or(hash1,hash2))` where you need to define a hash function which will work on your dataset (maybe md5,sha-1 are a choice) and depending on how you store the bits you can have different implementations of he `or` (if the length of 32 is sufficient you can go for a long and replace by the normal  bitwise OR operation)

Comment: For python you have [pyboom](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pybloom/1.0.2), but you can also find other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Has anyone able to solve this problem? My guess is that the issue is because of shuffling data between executors. I used ,ridiculously, two small datasets ( 10 records ) with no missing key and still the join operation was stuck. I had to eventually kill the instance. The only thing which could help in my case was cache().

If we take above example

```
rdd1=sc.textFile(hdfs_dir1).map(lambda row: (getKey1(row),getData1(row)))
rdd2=sc.textFile(hdfs_dir2).map(lambda row: (getKey2(row),getData2(row)))
# cache it
rdd1.cache()
rdd2.cache()
# I also tried rdd1.collect() and rdd2.collect() to get data cached
# then try the joins 
result=rdd1.join(rdd2)
# I would get the answer 
result.collect() # it works
```

I am not able to find why caching works though ( Apparently, it should have worked otherwise too ie without cache() ).

Answer (score 1):

You can narrow down whether this is a problem with the collect() call by calling a count instead to see if it is an issue pulling the results into the driver:

```
result=rdd1.join(rdd2).count()
```

If the count works, it might be best to add a sample or limit, then call collect() if you're attempting to view the results.

You can also look at the task in the Spark UI to see if a task has been assigned to a particular executor and use the UI again to look at the executor logs. Within the executors tab, you can take a thread dump of the executor that is handling the task. If you take a few thread dumps and compare them, check to see if there's a thread that's hung.

Look at the driver log4j logs, stdout / stderr logs for any additional errors.

Comment: My actual code is `result=rdd1.join(rdd2).map(lambda x:(x[...],1)).reduceByKey(add).collect()` so memory is probably isn't the issue, I see no errors in the `pyspark` console (and I see way too many `INFO` logs), should I expect to see them in the log files ?

Comment: Have you tried calling count() instead of collect() and it returns without any issues? How are you deploying this, yarn, standalone, mesos? You may see something in the logs, but it depends on how this is configured. There 3 different log files, log4j, stdout, and stderr. Sounds like the log4j configuration is printed on your console.